# Get access to array inside object in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am new to angularjs so I dont know how to push any value to array at particular position. For example :

```
$scope.atparticular.push = 
[

{questionText: 'queston1',questionId: '1',answerlst:[{answerText:'answer1',answerId: 'a1'},{answerText: 'answer2',answerId: 'a2'},{answerText: 'answer3',answerId: 'a3'}]},

{questionText: 'row2queston1',questionId: 'rq1',answerlst:[{answerText:'row2answer1',answerId: 'row2a1'},{answerText: 'row2answer2',answerId: 'row2a2'},{answerText: 'row2answer3',answerId: 'row2a3'}]}

];
```

If this is my object containing list and if I want to append answerlst with one more position containing empty values such as :

```
$scope.atparticular.push = 
    [

    {questionText: 'queston1',questionId: '1',answerlst:[{answerText:'answer1',answerId: 'a1'},{answerText: 'answer2',answerId: 'a2'},{answerText: 'answer3',answerId: 'a3'},{answerText: '',answerId: ''}]},

    {questionText: 'row2queston1',questionId: 'rq1',answerlst:[{answerText:'row2answer1',answerId: 'row2a1'},{answerText: 'row2answer2',answerId: 'row2a2'},{answerText: 'row2answer3',answerId: 'row2a3'},{answerText: '',answerId: ''}]}

    ];
```

Please give some suggestion. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to add an object at the end of the array `answerlst` of the first element of the array `$scope.atparticular.push`.

So you want:

```
$scope.atparticular.push[0].answerlst.push({answerText: '',answerId: ''});
```

Note that this has nothing to do with angularJS per se. It's just plain JavaScript.

Comment: Cannot read property 'answerlst' of undefined.After doing this

Comment: Then it means that the object $scope.atparticular is not the one you posted in your question. Use your debugger and check what it really contains

Comment: [
{"answerlst":[{"answerText":"sads","answerId":126},{"answerText":"dfsdf","an
swerId":128},{"answerText":"dfsd","answerId":130}],"questionId":49,"questionText
":"1df"},

{"answerlst":[{"answerText":"fdsdf","answerId":127},{"answerText":"dsfs
d","answerId":129},{"answerText":"dsfds","answerId":131}],"questionId":50,"quest
ionText":"2dsf"}

]

Comment: Same object getting after debugger.

Comment: It doesn't contain what you posted at the moment the line I posted in my answer is executed. If it did, you wouldn't get this exception.

Comment: sorry, but if you see the output it is exactly what I posted in my question.I think we can not get the direct access to answerlst.Beacuse its angularjs.

Comment: Post a plunkr or JSFiddle reproducing the problem.

Comment: sorry there i cant find angular version(1.2.9.min.js)

Comment: var taskManagerModule = angular.module('MyTable', []);
  taskManagerModule.controller('MainController', [ '$scope','$http', function($scope,$http){

$scope.rows = ["",{"answerlst":[{"answerText":"sads","answerId":126},{"answerText":"dfsdf","answerId":128},{"answerText":"dfsd","answerId":130}],"questionId":49,"questionText":"1df"},{"answerlst":[{"answerText":"fdsdf","answerId":127},{"answerText":"dsfsd","answerId":129},{"answerText":"dsfds","answerId":131}],"questionId":50,"questionText":"2dsf"}];

                
$scope.rows.push[1].answerlst.push({answerText: '',answerId: ''});

Comment: It has been resolved with  $scope.rows[0].answerlst.push({answerText: '',answerId: ''});